# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"

Tags: java, csv, parsing, int, java.util.scanner

So I am reading in a CSV file which works fine if everything is a string. But when i try and parse Integers out of the file it no longer will work.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("top250.csv"));
    scanner.useDelimiter(",");

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
       String line = scanner.nextLine();
       System.out.println(line);

      String[] parts = line.split(",");
      String rank = parts[0].trim();
      System.out.println(rank);
      int real_rank = Integer.parseInt(rank);
}
```

Output:

```
 ﻿1, The Shawshank Redemption ,9.2,1994
 ﻿1
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input  string: "﻿1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at movieranker.MovieRanker.createData(MovieRanker.java:45)
at movieranker.MovieRanker.main(MovieRanker.java:25)
```

Comment: No error with your code, just the scanner.useDelimiter(","); is strange. Using this would give one section every line. So I am pretty sure that code and output aren't matching. Please recheck and edit!

Comment: How many characters is the "1"? Maybe there is some additional none printable character you can not paste that isnt caught by the trim().

Comment: Just for checking, could you please send your complete code?

Comment: There's an invisible character. I'm getting `rank.length() == 2`. The leading character has unicode value 65279, which is [this character](http://unicode-table.com/en/FEFF/)

Comment: @4castle If you try my method, does that remove the character? It works in eclipse for me but just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException` indicates that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

This exception occurs because in the case that only a number is inputed, the actual string produced may have some invisible charachters and not `"1"`. Thus, the format is incorrect. A simple fix would be:

Line changed from:

```
int real_rank = Integer.parseInt(rank);
```

to:

```
rank = rank.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "")
int real_rank = Integer.parseInt(rank); //remove everything non-digit from your input, including \n symbols
```

Comment: @DominikK Maybe some invisible charachters are left. Try this instead. If it doesn't work, I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: The invisible character was the [zero width no-break space](http://unicode-table.com/en/FEFF/).

Comment: @4castle Why is that inserted?

Comment: It must have just crept in from copy/pasting or some weird key combo. Maybe they used a program to generate it which uses it as the delimiter.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj I think it has to do with the way I saved the csv possibly in the wrong encoding.

Comment: @DylanKolson Ah Thanks. I was rally curious.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think because your data file contains an [UTF-8 BOM.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)

You have three alternatives: 
edit your source data file to remove the BOM, or you can add some code to deal with the BOM. For the first option use Notepad++ and remove the BOM. 
or use a Libarie which can handle it .. i like http://www.univocity.com/pages/about-parsers